# How do I get past the 4th phase of jack-in-the-box?

Tags: castle-of-illusion

I've been trying to beat the jack-in-the-box of Castle of Illusion, and I'm stuck in the 4th phase (where he sticks out all 4 springs and swings them around).
**How do I beat the boss' 4th phase?**

Answer (score 2):

Youtube searching (and realizing you're probably talking about the 2013 game) gives me a video where the proper course of action seems to be to, um, jump over the springs.